# Facebook Unsafe JavaScript Attempt

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0, django-facebook

Having problems authenticating using OAuth2.0 with the JS SDK

1) created facebook website app with domain 'urchinapp.com' site url 'http://local.urchinapp.com:8000/'
2) I edited my /etc/hosts file to redirect local.urchinapp.com to localhost
3) started app on local.urchinapp.com:8000 and visited page.

The popup does appear and ask for the appropriate permissions, but once the page reloads I get the following error in the web inspector console:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request from frame with
>   URL http://local.urchinapp.com:8000/. Domains, protocols and ports
>   must match.

UPDATE:
Using the Django-Facebook library is probably the problem: using the F.connect() call from _facebook_js.html gives me errors while loading the original JS SDK from Facebook gives me no problems. However, I'd like to use _facebook_js.html as it gives me more seamless integration with server-side Python calls to the Graph API, etc.

Furthermore, I am actually able to create posts and access permissions. But the app continues to raise 'Unsafe JavaScript' errors.

I am running this on Chrome.

Comment: Did yo manage to solve this? I'm having similar problems

Comment: not really. Sometimes Google Chrome complains about domain issues - you might want to try using Firefox. I ended up running away from the problem by switching to everyauth in NodeJS

Comment: Firefox does work fine, but I'm building or iPhone and safari is throwing the same errors.